# Migrate User Passwords from One DB to Another

Tags: django, mongodb, postgresql, authentication, bcrypt

I'm currently using mongoDB as my application DB and hashing passwords with bcrypt. I'm going to be moving over to a Django application as well as a PostgreSQL DB and will be transferring all my users over to that, and using Django's built in authentication system. I'm not sure how to handle the passwords, however. Is it possible to move users over without requiring all users to reset their passwords?

Comment: Django saves a hash of your password combined with a salt. bcrypt uses a totally different way for encryption. If there is a way to reverse the hashed password by bcrypt then yes you can (I'm almost 100% sure there isn't a way to reverse though unless brute forcing your way through them which will take YEARS), otherwise, password reset is your way to go I guess.

Comment: @devdob That's the answer I was fearing... Thanks though :)

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news :s. Hope you can get things sorted :)

Comment: According to the docs, Django supports bcrypt encoded passwords "with minimal effort" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/.